# Lock/Unlock All Forms

Tags: ms-access

I have five forms that are used to input data into a database.

I want to know if I can lock and unlock all forms with the click of a button OR a pin code/password. The user is able to access all forms and add data to them but I would like there to be some form of security.

Within a **new form**, a **username and password** would be used to **unlock all forms** so that the user **can enter data** into them. Vice versa, a button should **log the user out** and **lock all forms**, preventing them from entering data into the forms.

[image] The form looks like this
[image] There would be a button at the bottom that would close and lock all forms

I am using Access 2016

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by lock/unlock? The user cannot open? The user cannot add data? The forms are not available in the navigation pane? There are a few ways to do this but are dependent on what you're trying to accomplish. Also please add the version of Access you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question with what I wanted to do. A new form with a login ID and password should unlock all forms and allow the user to enter data. Vice versa, a button should lock all forms and disable the user from viewing and entering data into the forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent editing is by setting the `RecordsetType` to 2 (Snapshot).

This should give you an idea, it locks/unlocks all opened forms:

```vb
Public Sub LockAllOpenForms(doLock As Boolean)

    Dim F As Form

    For Each F In Forms
        ' 2 = Snapshot = locked, 0 = Dynaset = editable
        F.RecordsetType = IIf(doLock, 2, 0)
    Next F

End Sub
```

To affect future forms, you need e.g. a public variable `glbLocked` set by your password form, and then in each data input form:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If glbLocked Then Me.RecordsetType = 2

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes but I would like to lock *all* forms using *one* pin/password.

Comment: Yeah well, of course you'll have to create a password entry form which calls the above sub. And see edit.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need to disable changing in forms and subforms. 
You can use form's properties `.AllowEdits=False`, `.AllowDeletions=False` and `.AllowAdditions = False`. If you change those properties, subforms also will be locked

To unlock just use `True` as a value for those properties. When user clicks Unlock button, procedure should ask PIN code. If entered correct PIN code, change .Allow* properties to True.

Comment: This wouldn't allow the user to *unlock all forms* by entering a pin or password. Thank you though.